# Why doesn't $(e^{A})^{-1} = e^{-A}$ hold for a symmetric matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, exponential-distribution, matrix-inverse, symmetry

$e^A$ is just the $A$ matrix with all of its elements exponentiated, called a matrix exponential.

It follows that [the inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364976/inverse-of-a-matrix-exponential-eat-1-e-at) $(e^{A})^{-1} = e^{-A}$ for square matrices, although I could find nothing on whether this is supposed to still hold for symmetric matrices. In my case $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

In Python, I try to test the previous equality, but found that it doesn't hold for a symmetric matrix. not sure why or if I've done something wrong

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1.4,0.02,0.01],
             [0.02,1.5,0.03],
             [0.01,0.03,1.6]])
print(A)

print(np.linalg.inv(np.exp(A)))
print(np.exp(-A))
```

which outputs

```
[[1.4  0.02 0.01]
 [0.02 1.5  0.03]
 [0.01 0.03 1.6 ]]

[[ 0.27060306 -0.05136872 -0.04449588]
 [-0.05136872  0.24409113 -0.04030659]
 [-0.04449588 -0.04030659  0.21935596]]

[[0.24659696 0.98019867 0.99004983]
 [0.98019867 0.22313016 0.97044553]
 [0.99004983 0.97044553 0.20189652]]
```

The last two matrices should be equal to each other, but they're not

Comment: I think your reasoning ultimately implies that the inverse of a matrix should equal the original matrix with each element inverted, and this is not the case even for symmetric matrices.

Comment: no i wasn't going to take it that far. i will have to look for a way to disambiguate the matrix whose elements are exponentiated from the matrix exponential though. there doesn't seem to be a symbol for it since $e^A$ only can be used for the second

Comment: I guessed you were not going to take it that far, but if you follow through your argumentation, I think you will end up at what I indicated. At least I ended up there following the post. (Possibly by mistake.)

Comment: worth watching out that I don't do that nevertheless. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It would answer your question, because this is where the argument leads us to, and we know this cannot be correct. I was going to write this up, but you have already accepted another answer, so I will spare the effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a case of reasoning from a false premise.

1. The [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) is **not** defined as the exponentiation of each *element* of a matrix. Instead, the definition of a matrix exponential is
   $$
   \exp(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} X^k
   $$
   for a square matrix $X$.

   If you want to exponentiate a matrix, you'll need to use a function like `scipy.linalg.expm`. However, note that matrix exponentials are not easily done in general. See:
   Cleve Moler,  Charles Van Loan. "Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later". *Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics*, Vol. 45, No. 1
2. The function `np.exp` doesn't compute a matrix exponential. Instead, it's a function that exponentiates the elements of `A`. The documentation tells you as much.

Comment: but the function `np.exp(A)` does exponentiate the elements of $A$

Comment: Yes, it does exponentiate the elements of `A`. That's because `np.exp` is not a matrix exponential. Instead, it's a function that exponentiates the elements of `A`. The documentation tells you as much.

Comment: (+1) Matrix exponent is `scipy.linalg.expm`

Comment: how can I properly disambiguate a matrix whose elements are exponentiated, from the true matrix exponential $e^A$, using math notation? and does the inverse of the former follow from any special properties/rules as did the latter?

Comment: @develarist It seems you have an outstanding question about the difference between a matrix exponential and exponentiating the elements of a matrix. This is perfectly fine, but it's a question of mathematics, not statistics. You'd best ask a question in math.SE, and be sure to explain what, specifically, is giving you trouble.

Comment: @gunes It couldn't find the function you recommended `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'linalg'`

Comment: I'm not going to troubleshoot your python problems, but the function has a documentation page. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html so I don't think the problem lies with `scipy`.

Comment: strangely I had to import the function directly on its own `from scipy.linalg import expm`. anyway thanks

Comment: @Sycorax Is the matrix exponential a matrix itself that is the same shape as the original?$\exp(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} X^k$ looks like a scalar value, not a matrix

Comment: @develarist only if $X$ is scalar.